# SqlMetal alternative for Entity Framework 4

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I used to prefer using SqlMetal to the OR Designer in Visual Studio when generating my Linq2SQL model.

So, my question is: Is there an equivalent to SqlMetal for generating EF4 models, i.e. a command-line tool for rebuilding my EF classes in one step?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF has a tool called [EDM Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx).

Comment: It has been updated to Work better with EF6 - https://github.com/cincuranet/EdmGen2